# Formatting a date to a specific format

Tags: php, date, date-formatting

I have the following data available : `01/02/2014`

What I need to format to is: `2014-01-02 00:00:00`

What is the best way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 4):

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '01/02/2014');
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Z8K79F)

Comment: OP wants to truncate the time by the looks of it. This answer keeps the current time

Comment: Yep. Forgot it does that. Updated.

Answer (score 2):

```
$val="01/02/2014";
echo  date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($val));
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/93140)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should try it yourself.
you should study php date format documentation : http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php
Live demo: 
https://eval.in/93149

```
$d = "01/02/2014";

echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($d));
```

OUTPUT:

```
2014-01-02 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

By using PHP date function

```
$date = "1st April 2000";
```

OR

```
$date = "01/04/2000";

echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($date));
```

Comment: This outputs `2000-04-01` but with no `00:00:00`.

Comment: Now the Output will be 2000-04-01 00:00:00, for those variables.